# How to authenticate with Pear SOAP_Client

Tags: php, soap, magento, pear

I am trying to login to my magento's web services from a server that does not have SoapClient enabled.  So I figured I would install and use Pear's [SOAP_Client](http://pear.php.net/package/SOAP/docs/0.12.0/SOAP/SOAP_Client.html)  but I can't figure out how to login.

With SoapClient I use:

```
$client = new SoapClient($WSDL);
$session = $client->login($user, $api_key);
$response = $client->call($session, $method, $arguments);
```

But I can't find an analog to the `login` method for SOAP_Client

I gather that I should be setting something in the $proxy_params of the constructor, but I can't find what the indexes should be.

```
$proxy_params = array();
$client = new SOAP_Client($wsdl, true, false, $proxy_params);
$client->call($method, $arguments)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out, and there are a couple of factors here.

1. There isn't a login function for SoapClient, the login I was calling is a call as defined in the WSDL
2. The various magento API methods are not defined in the WSDL, you provide an argument resource method to method defined as `call` by the WSDL.  This created a bit of confusion because using `$client->call()` seems to invoke `call` as defined by the SOAP_Client class, so I need to use `$client->call('call')` to invoke the SOAP method `call`

The final code ended up being:

```
$method = 'catalog_product.info';
$args = array($product_id);

$client = new SOAP_Client($wsdl, true);
$session_id = $client->call(
    'login',
    array(
        'username'=>$username,
        'apiKey'=> $pasword
    )
);
$ret = $client->call(
    'call',
    array(
        'sessionId'=>$session_id,
        'resourcePath'=>$method,
        'args'=>$args
    )
);
```